# Not able to show/hide div using Jquery on Asp.Net RadioButtonList item selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a asp.net RadioButtonList Control and a  I want to hide or display these  based on RadioButtonList selection change using Jquery. Please guide me why I am not able to do it when using the same code with in

**My aspx**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"
type = "text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
type = "text/javascript"></script> 
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
rel = "Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#rdbrawmtrl input').click(function () {
            var value = $('#rdbrawmtrl input:checked').val();
            if (value == "Cotton") {
                $("#abc").show();
                $("#Panel6").hide();
            }
            if (value == "Wool") {
                $("#Panel6").show();
                $("#abc").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbrawmtrl" runat="server" Style="margin: 0 4px 8px 0;">
                            <asp:ListItem>Cotton</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Wool</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
<div id="abc" runat="server" style="display:none;">
//Some more controls
</div>
<div id="Panel6" runat="server" style="display:none;">
//some more controls
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

I have even tried to display jquery variable "value" but it showing no result.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#rdbrawmtrl input').click(function () {
            var value = $('#rdbrawmtrl input:checked').val();
            alert(value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please guide me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can not get HTML Element through id in javascript directly.
>   ASP.net is server side language and Javascript is client side so you
>   need to get CLient ID . Try this ..

```
$('#<%=rdbrawmtrl.ClientID%>').click(function(){
      // your code here ....
});
```

Comment: I have even tried this but still no result.
 `$("#<%=rdbrawmtrl.ClientID%> input").change(function () {
        var value = $("#<%=rdbrawmtrl.ClientID%> input:checked").val();
        alert(value);
    });`

Comment: Thanks Zohaib for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I have *assumed* that `ASP` renders your radio buttons as below.

```js
$("input[name='rdbrawmtrl']:radio").change(function() {

    var val = $(this).val();
    alert ( val );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
      <input name="rdbrawmtrl" id="rdbrawmtrl_0" type="radio" value="Cotton" />
     <label for="rdbrawmtrl_0">Cotton</label>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
      <input name="rdbrawmtrl" id="rdbrawmtrl_1" type="radio" value="Wool" />
     <label for="rdbrawmtrl_1">Wool</label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Edit:** Based on your comment, try the following.

```
$("input[id^='ContentPlaceHolder1_rdbrawmtrl']:radio").change(function() {

    var val = $(this).val();
    alert ( val );
});
```

Comment: @Ishettyl: My Radiobutton are rendered like this:
`<input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rdbrawmtrl_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rdbrawmtrl" value="Cotton" /><label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_rdbrawmtrl_0">Cotton</label>`
I have followed your suggestion, but it is also not working.

Comment: @Ishettyl: After following your suggestion it is giving me an Uncaught Type  error which says- $(...).on is not a function
`$("input[name='ContentPlaceHolder1_rdbrawmtrl']:radio").on("change", function () {`

Comment: That's because you're loading 2 versions of jQuery (1.4 that overrides 1.8.3) which you should not! Use only one version, preferably 1.8.3. I have edited the code to work with both anyway.

Comment: @Ishettyl: Even after using one library file i.e jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
still I am not getting any result.
`$("input[id^='ContentPlaceHolder1_rdbrawmtrl']:radio").on("change", function () {

        var val = $(this).val();
        alert(val);
    });`

Comment: @Ishettyl: Thanks dear for your support, I have accepted the answer submitted by Zohaib you can check.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to retrieve value because your ASP.NET RadioButton is rendered like this in browser:-

```
<tr>
  <td>
     <input name="rdbrawmtrl" id="rdbrawmtrl_0" type="radio" value="Cotton">
     <label for="rdbrawmtrl_0">Cotton</label>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
     <input name="rdbrawmtrl" id="rdbrawmtrl_1" type="radio" value="Wool">
     <label for="rdbrawmtrl_1">Wool</label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

As you can see the Id will be generated dynamically for each radio button. You should write a selector on `name` attribute like this:-

```
$('input[name="rdbrawmtrl"]').click(function () {
     var value = $(this).val();
     alert(value);
});
```

**Update:**

Having a Master Page will not only change the `Id` dynamically but also the `name` attribute. You can add a class to your RadioButtonList like this:-

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbrawmtrl" runat="server" Style="margin: 0 4px 8px 0;" 
                      CssClass="clsrdbrawmtrl">
```

Then you can find the radio buttons present inside it like this:-

```
$('input[type="radio"]',$('.clsrdbrawmtrl')).click(function () {
     alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: You mean to say like this-
`$('input[name="rdbrawmtrl"]').click(function () {
        var value = $('input[name="rdbrawmtrl"] input:checked').val();
        alert(value);
    });`
this is not working.

Comment: Still not working brother. I am fed up with this problem. My code is running fine when I am not using master page i.e. when I am writing this code within simple HTML page. But the it is not working within master page contentplaceholder.

Comment: @Omi - Not working as in? What is the error? It's working just fine for me.

Comment: Thanks brother for your support. Actually there was no error. I have accepted the answer by Zohaib with the edit mentioned above you can check. Thanks again for helping me.

Comment: @Omi - Okay bro. No issues:)